# AVCaptureSession - Capturing within a certain section of the frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm using AVCaptureSession to create a QR code scanner with AVCaptureMetadataOutput.

Everything is working as expected, however I'm wanting to put a graphical overlay on the scanner. In doing so, I'd like the scanner to only scan once the QR code is in a given section of the frame. Currently, it detects the QR code anywhere thats in the view, and I'd like it to trigger only when in the middle of the screen.

Is this even possible? For AVCapturePreviewLayer, I'm setting rectForMetadataOutputRectOfInterest but it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe I'm doing this wrong?

Some insight would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this, but I believe this can be achieved. You see, when you catch the `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`, you can use the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to get the QR code frame within the view, that's useful when you want to draw a rectangle around the captured QR.

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard let readableCode = metadataObjects.first as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject, let code = readableCode.stringValue else { return }

    if let barcodeObject = videoPreview?.transformedMetadataObject(for: readableCode) {
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barcodeObject.bounds
    }
    stopReading()
    didRead?(code)
}
```

You could use that `barcodeObject` to then ask if your rect contains the barcode using [CGRect's contains(_:) method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1454186-contains)

```
if qrReader.frame.contains(barcodeObject.bounds) {
    stopReading()
    didRead?(code)
}
```

I think that could/should work.